# How to count elements inside an element specified by object?

Tags: jquery

I bet this has a simple answer.

I want to count the number of TD elements inside a row, yet i can't seem to find the right syntax.

```
var row = $('#album_cell'+currentCell).parent();
var n = $("td",row).length();
```

This returns an error obviously as i don't know how to specify that. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var row = $('#album_cell'+currentCell).parent();
var childrenCount = row.children('td').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this syntax :

```
$( "#table > td" ).size()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
var row = $('#album_cell'+currentCell).parent().find("td").length;
```

Or Alternately

```
var row = $('#album_cell'+currentCell).parent().find("td").size();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use:

```
$('#yourtableid td').length
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/LU7Hh/1

Comment: Ya i couldn't just do that in my case